# Разборка jquery on

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте, не могу разобраться в чем дело.

[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/N7xAr/9/)

При нажатии вниз контент прокручивается вниз, и вверх соответственно. но после кнопки 'Загрузить через html' Ничего не работает.

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Решение](http://jsfiddle.net/N7xAr/10/)

Answer (score 0):

Так вы же заменяете DOM. После того как заменили нужно снова вешать события. [Или не менять ссылки](http://jsfiddle.net/H454m/)